# Define function name with text field 2

Tags: java

how to define (+,-,/,*) in java

example

```
 int or double or String a = + ;
    System.out.println(1a1);
```

as result we must get 2

thanks

Comment: You can't do that.   You need to use `if` or `switch` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't overload operators like that in Java, it is simply not supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
String operator="";
switch(operator)
    {
        case "+":
            // add
            break;

        case "-" :
            //subtract
    }
```

You can do this only in 1.7 and not in 1.6

I mean use String with a switch case.